# Xcode - Changing library reference path

Tags: macos, cocoa

So I installed Xcode(4.6.3) today & was trying to Build a sample project.It uses a framework Authenticate. Project crashes after successful build saying Authenticate.framework image not found. Searched for the error & found out that a Copy File build phase need to be added. However the issue still exist.

The error message is -

dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/Authenticator.framework/Versions/A/Authenticator
  Referenced from: /Users/Matt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageLoader/Build/Products/Debug/ImageLoader.app/Contents/MacOS/ImageLoader
  Reason: image not found

Found out that i have the framework @  /Users/Matt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageLoader/Build/Products/Debug/ImageLoader.app/Contents/Frameworks

So how can i change this default reference path Xcode is using?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need to add an @rpath entry to your .xcconfig file. It would probably look something like this:

```
LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = @loader_path/../Frameworks/
```

Comment: Was trying random things & in the Copy Files build phase changed the 'Destination' drop down value from Frameworks to Products Directory & the issue is resolved now. Can anyone suggest any good article on the various Xcode Build Settings? Went through the Apple Documentation, not much explanations there.